# php strtotime() values not working as expected

Tags: php, date, strtotime

this code keeps telling me that $lasUpdate is always greater than $yesterday no matter the change i make to $yesterday result is (12/31/14 is greater than 01/19/15 no update needed). i feel like i'm missing something simple thank you in advance it is greatly appreciated.

```
$result['MAX(Date)']='12/31/14';
$lastUpdate = date('m/d/y', strtotime($result['MAX(Date)']));
$yesterday = date('m/d/y', strtotime('-1 day'));

if($lastUpdate<$yesterday){echo $lastUpdate.'is less '.$yesterday.'<br>'.'update needed';}
if($lastUpdate>=$yesterday){echo $lastUpdate.'is greater than '.$yesterday.'<br>'.'no update needed';
```

Comment: The output of `date` is a string. A string compared to a string using `>=` will return `true`. In your scenario, you may as well be doing `0 < 0` and `0 >= 0`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> 12/31/14 is greater than 01/19/15

Because `1` is greater than `0`. If you want to compare dates that way you will need to store them in a different format (from most to least significant digit), for example `Ymd`.

Or store the timestamps you are making in the different variables and compare them.

Comment: So if you did `'12/31/14' > '01/19/15'`, do you think that will evaluate to `true`? While your understanding is incorrect, your answer was probably accepted because your `Ymd` suggestion actually allowed PHP to type-juggle the string into an integer.

Comment: Nice - forgot PHP just farts out after it hits the first non-numeric-type character instead of just returning `0` entirely.

Comment: Even though i think your answer is more thorough (hence the upvote) I'm not sure that you're right about comparing two (non numeric) strings in this way. Try few examples with strings that have no numbers in them at all.

Answer (score 2):

You have fallen victim to PHP type juggling with strings. A `date` function has a return value of a string. You *cannot* compare dates in their string format since PHP will juggle strings into integers in the context of a comparison. The only exception is if the string is a valid number. In essence, you are doing:

```
if ('12/31/14' < '01/19/15') { ... }
if ('12/31/14' >= '01/19/15') { ... }
```

Which PHP type juggles to:

```
if (12 < 1) { ... }
if (12 >= 1) { ... }
```

And returns `false` on the first instance, and `true` on the second instance.

Your solution is to not wrap `date` around the `strtotime` functions, and just use the returned timestamps from the `strtotime` functions themselves to compare UNIX timestamps directly:

```
$lastUpdate = strtotime($result['MAX(Date)']);
$yesterday = strtotime('-1 day');
```

You will however want to use `date` when you do the `echo` back to the user so they have a meaningful date string to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$lastUpdate = strtotime($result['MAX(Date)']);
$yesterday = strtotime('-1 day');

if ($lastUpdate < $yesterday) { /* do Something */ }
```